# TextView in relative layout doesn't expand to fill available space

Tags: android, android-layout

why does the gray box (transaction_amount) in the following layout doesn't expand to full space available even though the layout:height is match parent for it.

[image]

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/transaction_amount"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
    tools:text="100"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/transaction_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/transaction_amount"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
    tools:text="Mast Kalandar Dinner"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shared_bw_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/transaction_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/transaction_amount"
    android:layout_below="@id/transaction_name"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
    android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
    android:text="Shared Between"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shared_bw_csv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/shared_bw_label"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/shared_bw_label"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
    android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
    tools:text="Ashu, Amol"/>
```

Comment: Try changing the height to match_parent

Comment: On your question you mentioned you made the "width" match_parent, but that empty space was caused of the height, then you should fix the problem by changing the height.

Comment: sorry I meant to write layout_height. In the code layout_height is match_parent

Comment: Maybe because the parent of that textview has no declared height value, thus there's no value to be iherited by the match_parent as height. Try putting some value to that textviews parent.

Comment: Did my answer helped you? If not please inform me so i can give you a better code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `layout` instead, im sure it will help you.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#ffa"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="100"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```